For an Image with Source bound to a URL, how do I save the displayed image on disk?
Say I have an Image whose Source comes from a binding expression, bound to a URL (as a string):
<Image Source="{Binding WebformatUrl}" />

WPF downloads the image and displays it.
On a user interaction (specifically, a button click), I'd like to save to disk the image WPF has downloaded. How can I do this?

Do you want to save the image on user interaction or immediately after download? In the latter case, you could manually perfom a web request and directly save the downloaded binary content to file, but you would somehow need to automatically determine a file name. Please clarify your requirement.

@Clemens I want to save on user interaction. Will edit shortly.

You could save any ImageSource to file with the following method:
public static void SaveImageSource(ImageSource imageSource, string path)
{
    if (imageSource is not BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Can only save BitmapSource");
    }

    BitmapEncoder encoder = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower() switch
    {
        ".png" => new PngBitmapEncoder(),
        ".jpg" or ".jpeg" => new JpegBitmapEncoder(),
        ".tif" or ".tiff" => new TiffBitmapEncoder(),
        ".gif" => new GifBitmapEncoder(),
        ".wmp" => new WmpBitmapEncoder(),
        ".bmp" => new BmpBitmapEncoder(),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unknown image file format"),
    };

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

    using var fileStream = File.Create(path);

    encoder.Save(fileStream);
}

Given an Image element like
<Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding WebformatUrl}" />

you would call
SaveImageSource(image.Source, fileName);

where fileName may for example be assigned from the FileName property of an OpenFileDialog that you had opened in a Button Click event handler.

If the original image was say a JPEG, then converted into WPF's native format (BitmapSource?) then converted into some other format to save on disk, won't all those conversions degrade the image? That has more weight to me than matching the saved file format with the original file format; I don't particularly need the original file format, only that modern browsers can display it as an image.

Maybe the most efficient approach would be to download and store the original web response content as byte array in your view model. Then write that byte array to file in a view model ICommand implementation. But encoding in a different format won't necessarily degrade quality, especially when you use a format without compression like PNG.

I have added another answer with that completely different approach.

I don't really need something more efficient for code that depends on a user click (as opposed to something run automatically); particularly since most of the downloaded images will not be saved to disk. (My main concern in my previous comment was image degradation, which you addressed in a different comment.) But this answer is what I'm looking for.

Under what circumstances would imageSource not be a BitmapSource?

An image downloaded from the web would always be a BitmapSource, so you could safely change the type of the first parameter to BitmapSource and call SaveImageSource((BitmapSource)image.Source, fileName);.

Your view model could manually perform a web request to download and store the image buffer.
It could look like shown below, where the Binding would change to
<Image Source="{Binding WebformatBuffer, IsAsync=True}"/>

The simplified view model:
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new();
    private string webformatUrl;
    private byte[] webformatBuffer;

    public string WebformatUrl
    {
        get => webformatUrl;
        set
        {
            webformatUrl = value;
            webformatBuffer = null;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WebformatUrl));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WebformatBuffer));
        }
    }

    public byte[] WebformatBuffer
    {
        get
        {
            if (webformatBuffer == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(webformatUrl))
            {
                // we can only use synchronous HttpClient methods here

                var response = httpClient.Send(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, webformatUrl));

                using var contentStream = response.Content.ReadAsStream();
                using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                contentStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                webformatBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            return webformatBuffer;
        }
    }
}

Now you could add an ICommand property that saves webformatBuffer to file.

This looks intriguing (I've upvoted), but I don't need the extra efficiency, which does come at a cost of complexity. Particularly since most of the downloaded images will not be saved to disk by the user.

Your question asks:

[...] How do I save the displayed image on disk?

The first thing you need, if you're going to "save the displayed image", is the actual ImageSource for the displayed image. Then you can call SaveImageSource(imageSource) from Clemens' answer with that source.

However, the question adds this onerous requirement:

For an Image with Source bound to a URL

What doesn't help in terms of saving the displayed image is having the URL that you used to load the image into the UI. So, if "image source is bound to url" is a strict requirement, options include manually perform a web request to download and store the image buffer as Clemens other answer has suggested, or handle the Loaded event of the <Image> as my now-removed first answer suggested. A third option would be naming <Image x:Name="displayedImage" Source="{Binding WebformatUrl}" /> which would at least let you reference displayedImage.Source in the code behind (but not in the data context).

However, if "image source is bound to url" isn't a stict requirement, it would be more straightforwared to bind the ImageSource, instead of the url string, to the data context. It's still necessary to respond to changes in WebformatUrl, and we do respond by synchronously downloading the bitmap and setting it as the CurrentImageSource. But this way, when it's time to save, we can reference CurrentImageSource in the DC without a lot of fuss and bother.
Xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image
        Source="{Binding CurrentImageSource}"
        Margin="20" />
    <Button 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Width="150" 
        Height="30"
        Margin="0,10"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Content="Save" 
        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
</Grid

DataContext
// <PackageReference Include = "CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.3.2" />
partial class ExistingBindingDataContext : ObservableObject // OR INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string SaveToPath { get; set; }
    public ExistingBindingDataContext() 
    {
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/79040060/5438626
            SaveImageSource(CurrentImageSource, SaveToPath);
        });
    }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    string _webFormatUrl = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    ImageSource? _currentImageSource = default;
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(SelectedImageIndex):
                WebFormatUrl = ComboBoxItems.Values.ToArray()[SelectedImageIndex];
                break;
            case nameof(WebFormatUrl):
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(WebFormatUrl);
                bitmap.EndInit();
                CurrentImageSource = bitmap;
                break;
        }
    }
    static void SaveImageSource(ImageSource imageSource, string path) { /* ... */}
}


If WPF accepts a string URL as a valid value for the Source property, why is it more "straightforward" to manipulate the BitmapImage by hand? Even if you mean there's no other way to access the raw binary data of the image, it's still not more "straightforward."

Also, in my case: 1. both filename and file format will not be chosen by the user, so no need for FileSaveDialog; 2. the URL is a property on the model, not a selection from predefined items, thus no need for the SelectedItemIndex property. These (and the messagebox prompting as to whether the file should be opened in an external editor) obscure the central parts of the answer: getting an encoder, adding a frame to the encoder, and saving to a FileStream.

Points taken. I've provided a more concise answer.

What doesn't help in terms of saving the displayed image is having the URL that you used to load the image into the UI. True, but I don't need it for that; I can access the WPF-generated ImageSource via the Source property. It's much more straightforward to do so, then to create a whole ViewModel.

You don't have a ViewModel (DataContext) already? What are you binding to exactly?

A POCO; I don't need anything more at the moment.

Might be a good clarification to the question, which "strongly implies" MVVM. I mean, it sound like the question s.b. "How do I save an ImageSource to disk?" At least that's the answer you accepted...

Not really. My starting point is the Image with Source bound to a URL; I wasn't aware that there's an automatic conversion from string to ImageSource.
